# Is the min-max rescaling or z-score normalization more appropriate when comparing data of vastly different mean, SD, and range?

Tags: python, normalization

I have six lists of data in `Python` where each list contains 23 items as follows.

```
list_1 = [-1.42, -1.87, -1.64, ...]
list_2 = [-1.56, -1.64, -1.98, ...]
list_3 = [-1.36, -1.44, -1.58, ...]

list_4 = [0.983, 0.956, 0.853, ...]
list_5 = [0.853, 0.953, 0.753, ...]
list_6 = [0.864, 0.835, 0.799, ...]
```

My goals are as follows:

1. First, I compute a linear regression (or slope) between every pair of `list_1, list_2 and list_3` and between every pair of `list_4, list_5 and list_6`. The result are thus two list of slopes for the list combinations 1-3 and 3-6. For example, I would first calculate the slope between `-1.42`, `-1.56` and `-1.36` when plotting them together.
2. Second, using a t-Test, I would like to statistically compare if the difference between the two resulting slope lists is significant or not.

Step 2 of course requires a normalization of the data that is best applied even before step 1, I assume. Otherwise it remains impossible to meaningfully compare the slopes between both resulting lists, since the original values between lists 1-3 and 4-6 vastly diverge.

**Question:** What kind or type of normalization would be the most appropriate here? Do I have to apply the min-max normalization, or is the z-score normalization required. Or, instead, do I need to apply a completly different type of normalization?

**Update:**
The following image tries to make it more clear what I attempt to answer. The question is: do the slopes in the left plot significantly differ from the slopes in the right plot? Note the different y-axis scale in both plots. My understanding was that a normalization is first required to answer this question. After reading the comments, I think that I need a complete different statistical approach, correct?

[image]

Comment: The t-test is not applicable here because of the strong dependencies among the slope estimates and also due to the multiple comparisons you are making.  Normalization won't fix that problem: it makes it worse, because it changes what you are comparing.  What is your statistical objective?  What are you trying to determine from this analysis?

Comment: I would like to test if the average slope between the two resulting "slope lists" significantly diverges or not. Phrased differently, I would like to know if the average slope of lists 1-3 and lists 4-6 is more or less the same or not (statistically estimated).

Comment: There are reasons to suppose such an average slope wouldn't have any meaning.  Could you tell us what it's intended to represent or estimate?

Comment: The data stems from neuroimaging time-series (fMRI). Lists 1-3 include the results of one kind of measurement, but in three different brain regions. Lists 4-6 include the results of another completly different kind of measurement, but again in the three same brain regions. My question is: although I am comparing two different measurements, as can be seen by the different absolute result levels when comparing lists 1-3 vs. 4-6, does the balance between regions 1, 2 and 3 remain the same between both measurements? I try to measure this balance via the slope across the three regions (lists).

Comment: It sounds like you want to compare the two sets of measurements, controlling for brain region.  You would need a multivariate regression, not an *ad hoc* averaging procedure.

Comment: Thanks. I added a picture to the initial post to make it more clear what my aim is. Do I understand you correctly that any normalization applied here is meaningless and has nothing to do with my goal? Thanks  again.